# No Send As permission after migrating mailbox from Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2010

Tags: email, windows-server-2008-r2, smtp, exchange-2007, exchange-2010

I'm in the middle of migrating to Exchange 2010 after finally getting everything in the event log cleared up

I migrated one users mailbox, and of course, there is an issue.

Any time the user sends HTML emails, they are stripped and the recipient receives a blank email (inside and outside organization, tested multiple accounts it isn't a client issue).

After investigation, the user has no send as permissions after the migration to Exchange 2010 (not even NT AUTHORITY\SELF). When trying to add this I get the following error and I don't know if it has anything to do with it:

> operation failed on win2k8dc1.domain.local this error is not retriable. access is denied active directory response 00000005. insuff_access_rights, data 0
>
> the user has insufficient access rights.

I also disabled all transport rules and anti virus email filtering (has been disabled on server, disabled it on users pc as well).

The user is using outlook 2007.

Comment: Jeff, I say this with the greatest respect - please don't take it the wrong way. Going by your questions over the past few days, you are having a lot of permissions problems that just shouldn't occur in a normal situation. I humbly submit that you have some underlying problem you don't know about (or don't totally understand) and you should really get a consultant in to give you some assistance. I certainly don't mean to deter you on Server Fault, but a consultant will probably give you a (relatively speaking) quick turnaround and hopefully solve your underlying problem too.

Comment: Ben, I actually have had outside consultants look, change things, and cause more problems.. example - whenever we migrated to exchange 2007, an outside consultant company came in to help with the process - during which so they didnt uninstall exchange 03, just shut the server down and deleted it from ad

Comment: i appreciate your response though - I'm actually thinking of handing this over to someone else cause it is pretty much driving me to the point of no return with fustration.

Comment: btw: steps i have taken to monitor of underlying problems, i have run the exchange 07 and 10 exBPA and corrected every thing that they discovered. thoroughly went over every servers event logs and fixed every warning and error i could possible find. and some microsoft tools to check for errors i dont remember the exact name. this system was setup by one guy, run by another guy, then handed to me. whenever i got it you could give it a -10 on an over best practice scale. everyone had permission tot he c: of the dc  when i got here

Comment: That is unfortunate you've had a bad experience. There is only so much troubleshooting you can do without actually seeing the server and environment it is in, which prompted my comment really. As always, I keep an eye on the Exchange related tags here on Server Fault, so if I can offer anything to your questions I'll certainly try to help you out.

Comment: don't take it the wrong way or anything - I appreciate all comments and ment no disrespect - I would probably suggest to someone to do the same :) i more than likely am over looking something, i dealt with a microsoft sql database that got corrupted some where along the line (navision), developing a new repair system in .net, this exchange server, then some wsus problems all in the last two weeks - i should probably take a vacation n come back with a fresh look on it

Comment: Whoops, sorry I goofed your title up. I guess I have my own 2003 -> 2010 migration on the brain :P

Comment: its cool, i actually answered my own question with the blank emails..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user has ever had domain admin rights then inherit permissions may be unchecked.  Ensure the ADUnC "view > advanced" option is enabled and look under security tab for that user for advanced and ensure inherit is checked.

Comment: the user once was infact was a domain admin - the include inheritable permissions was unchecked. this resolved the second issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like i said, overlooking something stupid

i have vipre enteprised installed on the server controlling all agents
the user has higher access - and installed avast antivirus - i thought it was just vipre

the user turned off avast, low and behold - there comes the email.